# Regarding generation of junit test cases of java classes

Tags: java, junit

I am pure developer and spent most of time in writing the java classes , but the case of junit test cases , I become little bit lazy is there any plugin that can be installed in eclipse that will generate my junit test cases automatically..!! Please advise

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102078/junit-test-case-generator

Comment: So are you saying that writing unit tests is not part of "pure development"? Also, any code generation tool like that is only going to give you a starting point template, not real test code.

Comment: There is no substitute for writing your unit tests and even if there was such a tool, I wouldn't touch it with a barge pole!

Comment: While we're on the subject, can anyone recommend a plugin that will write my code for me?

Comment: So you don't believe in test first development? (not judging) :)

Answer (score 0):

[MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) is an awesome plugin that generates test classes and allows easy navigation between test and class under test.  It can also generate test method stubs and mock boilerplate, but I don't think these are as useful.

As for the test code itself, the only way around writing it is to get someone else to write it (i.e. executable specifications).

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit plugin stubs out the methods for you, which is all you should need. It's up to you to know what and how to test. There is this tool from [Parasoft](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/capabilities/unit_testing.jsp;jsessionid=aaaaisOI3nunZb?redname=unit-testing&referred=unit-testing), but I have never used it, so can't say how it is.